# Setting OutputCache in with action filter (Asp.Net MVC 4.6)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, outputcache

I must be overlooking something really stupid, I've read lots of posts about this and tried out various suggested solutions, but somehow I'm unable to get the action filter to work.

The web.config contains

```
  <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="ServerAndClientDefault" duration="86400" location="ServerAndClient" varyByParam="none"/>
  </outputCacheProfiles>
```

If I use

[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "ServerAndClientDefault")]

everything works fine, the response headers show

Cache-Control: private, max-age=86385

Expires: Sat, 13 Apr 2019 15:42:59 GMT

Vary: *

In order to override vary * and to add an E-Tag, I created an action filter as follows:

```
public class OutputCacheProfileAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string CacheProfileName { get; set; }
    public HttpCacheability Cacheability { get; set; } = HttpCacheability.ServerAndPrivate;

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
        var cacheSection = (OutputCacheSettingsSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/caching/outputCacheSettings");
        var cacheProfile = cacheSection.OutputCacheProfiles[CacheProfileName];

        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);

        cache.SetCacheability(Cacheability);
        cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(cacheProfile.Duration));
        cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(cacheProfile.Duration));
        cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        cache.SetETag("test");
        cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);
        cache.VaryByParams.IgnoreParams = true;
    }
}
```

It is called with

[OutputCacheProfile(CacheProfileName = "ServerAndClientDefault")]

Now the headers always are

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate

Expires: -1

Pragma: no-cache

In the VS debugger I can see the correct values are taken from the profile, but they obviously don't get set properly. Nor is the E-Tag header added. Setting hard-coded values directly doesn't work either.

I also tried using OnActionExecuted, replacing the 'ed's with 'ing's (e.g. OnActionExecuting) and deriving from OutputCacheAttribute instead of ActionFilterAttribute. Somewhere I read about using reflection, but I don't really want to go down that route for fear of performance impact.

It should be straightforward, and there are no cache settings anywhere else, so why is this derived filter not working? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

For completeness, here what I tried deriving from OutputCacheAttribute:

```
public class OutputCacheProfileAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public OutputCacheProfileAttribute()
    {
        Duration = 86400;
        NoStore = false;
        Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient;
    }
}
```

In addition, in the same class I tried overriding OnActionExecuted with the same code as shown at the top. Neither worked.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Have a look on OutputCacheAttribute code https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/OutputCacheAttribute.cs that will help you

Comment: thanks, but I don't see what I can do with it that I haven't tried already; as mentioned, deriving from and overriding parts of OutputCacheAttribute didn't work; please let me know if you have a specific suggestion